# How do I wrap the content of a textbox inside a scrollviewer so that it scrolls when full in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have placed a textbox inside a `scrollviewer` control. The textbox is updated with content from my database, however when the box becomes full, the box resizes to fit more text. I would like the `scrollviewers` scroll feature to activate at this point, and allow the user to scroll to see more text. I have tried the following:

```
<ScrollViewer>
    <TextBox FontSize="14" TextWrapping="Wrap" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True"/>
</ScrollViewer>

<ScrollViewer>
    <TextBox FontSize="14" TextWrapping="Wrap" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" AcceptsReturn="True"/>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Any help would be much appreciated, Thanks.

Comment: What's the parent of the scrollviewer?

Comment: My Scrollviewer is within a grid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `ScroollViewer` attached properties directly on a `TextBox`. Specify also the maximum height of the `TextBox` - `MaxHeight`:

```
<TextBox ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
         ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" 
         ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True"
         FontSize="14" TextWrapping="Wrap" MaxHeight="300" />
```

No need to insert the `TextBox` inside the `ScrollViewer`.

Comment: Thanks I didnt realise TextBox had a ScrollViewer property. It almost worked but was still resizing. I have added a MaxHeight option and that worked so the scroll feature now enables. If you added that to the answer I'll be happy to mark it as the solution. Thanks again.  Edit: I meant If  you add that to your answer I'll mark it correct.

Answer (score 0):

you can implement scrolling functionality on a content control like